# Trying to design a mechanical system with vertical and horizontal movement

Tags: mechanism

I'm trying to devise a system to lift a 10kg weight a distance of 1.4m vertically, and allow it to move in/out a distance of 30cm. I'd like the motions to be able to occur simultaneously if possible.

I'm thinking for the vertical motion I can use a suspended climber system. However I am unsure as to how I devise a system for the horizontal motion (in the horizontal plane I need nothing to protrude - only when the device is told to extend, so a horizontal suspended climber system isn't a possible solution.

I'm thinking I will need to use 2 electric motors.

Also - I'd like to mount it to the side of a car - so lightweight and low power draw is a must.

Does anyone know if there is anything available that will do this? Or suggest how I could combine a couple of systems to make this work?

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen anything specific to your specifications, but it seems like you'd want to look into servo motors that meet your needs:
http://www.jameco.com/jameco/workshop/howitworks/how-servo-motors-work.html

and look for inspiration from automated storage and retrieval systems or perhaps a gripper arm that can extend horizontally but fold down vertically to avoid protruding.  Maybe not the best example for what you want but maybe it'll get you headed in the right directions from this vertical lift example from a robotics competition: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ioilEy1I8lY